# How to calculate the derivative of $f(M) = \operatorname{Trace}(M^pX)$ with respect to $M$?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, trace, symmetric-matrices

I have been thinking about this problem for a couple of months, and eventually failed. Could someone help me?

> Let $M$ and $X$ be two symmetric matrices with $M\succeq 0$ and $X=X^T$, and let $p$ be a nonzero real number $|p|\le 10$.  What is the derivative of $f$ with respect to $M$, where
>
> $$f(M) = \operatorname{Trace}(M^pX),$$
>
> and $\operatorname{Trace}(A)$ is the trace operator to calculate the sum of elements in diagonal line of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

Use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB) = {\rm Tr}(AB^T)
}$$
From this definition and the cyclic property
one can deduce the rearrangement rules
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A = B^T:A^T \\
A:BC &= B^TA:C = AC^T:B = I:A^TBC = I:BCA^T \\
}$$
If the matrices are symmetric, one can omit the transposes.

Consider the following function defined for integer $n$ values,
for which one can calculate the differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
f &= X:A^n \\
df
 &= X:\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} A^{k}\,dA\,A^{n-k-1}\right) \\
 &= \left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} A^{k}\,X\,A^{n-k-1}\right):dA \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}
 &= \left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} A^{k}\,X\,A^{n-k-1}\right)
 \;\doteq\; G \qquad\{{\rm the\,gradient}\} \\\\
}$$
To extend this result to the matrix $M$ with a rational exponent $p=\ell/m$

define the matrix $A$ such that
$$A^n = M^{\ell/m}\;\implies\; A^{mn}=M^{\ell}$$
Then find an expression for $dA$ in terms of $dM$, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
\left(\sum_{k=0}^{mn-1} A^{k}\,dA\,A^{mn-k-1}\right)
 &= \left(\sum_{j=0}^{\ell-1} M^{j}\,dM\,M^{\ell-j-1}\right) \\
}$$
To avoid tensors, vectorize the matrix expressions
$$\eqalign{
&a = {\rm vec}(A),\qquad m = {\rm vec}(M) \\
&\left(\sum_{k=0}^{mn-1} A^{k}\otimes A^{mn-k-1}\right)\,da
 = \left(\sum_{j=0}^{\ell-1} M^{j}\otimes M^{\ell-j-1}\right)\,dm \\
}$$
which can be abbreviated to $\,\big(B\,da = C\,dm\big).\,$
We'll also need two more vectorizations
$$\eqalign{
x &= {\rm vec}(X),\qquad
g &= {\rm vec}(G) 
 &= \left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} A^{k}\otimes A^{n-k-1}\right)x 
 \;\doteq\; Ex \\
}$$
Substitute all of this into the previous result to obtain
$$\eqalign{
df &= g:da \\&= Ex:B^{-1}C\,dm \\&= CB^{-1}Ex:dm \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial m} &= CB^{-1}Ex
\quad\implies\quad
\frac{\partial f}{\partial M} = {\rm vec}^{-1}\big(CB^{-1}Ex\big) \\
}$$
For non-rational exponents, it'll be even harder.

#### Update

The comments pointed out that the above formula only works for $n>0$.
To handle negative exponents, you can do the following.

Write the function in terms of the inverse matrix $V=A^{-1},\;$ 
calculate its differential in terms of $dV.\;$
Finally, substitute $dV=-V\,dA\,V,\;$ i.e. 
$$\eqalign{
f &= X:A^{-n} \\&= X:V^n \\
df
 &= \left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} V^{k}\,X\,V^{n-k-1}\right):dV \\
 &= -\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} V^{k}\,X\,V^{n-k-1}\right):V\,dA\,V \\
 &= -\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} V^{k+1}\,X\,V^{n-k}\right):dA \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}
 &= -\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} V^{k+1}\,X\,V^{n-k}\right) \\
}$$

Comment: It looks interesting. By the way, index $m$ can be confused with the vector $m$, I think.

Comment: @user550103 I noticed that, too. I wish the OP had not chosen $M$ as his main variable.

Comment: Thanks for your elegant deducing procedure. However, there is one thing at which I am still pullzed. That is if the inter n > 0 in your dedution?

$\frac{\partial tr(XM^{-1})}{\partial M} = M^{-1}XM^{-1}$. However, according to the 3rd bulk of equations, the calculated result is $XM^{-2} + M^{-1}XM^{-1} + M^{-2}X$.

Comment: @tulip123000 The answer has been updated to address negative exponents.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(A) = \operatorname{tr}(A)$ then

$df_A[H]=\operatorname{tr}H=(\operatorname{tr}\circ\operatorname{id})[H]=(\operatorname{tr}\circ\, dA_A)[H]$

for $A=M^pX$, and e.g., $p=2$, $dA_M=dM_M\,M\,X + M\,dM_M\,X$ and the chain rule gives (reusing letter $H$ for the auxiliary variable):

$df_M[H]=(\operatorname{tr}\circ\operatorname{dA_M})[H]=(\operatorname{tr}\circ\,(dM_M\,M\,X + M\,dM_M\,X))[H]=\operatorname{tr}(H\,M\,X + M\,H\,X)$

[If products of three symmetric matrices are considered, any permutation is allowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)), therefore

$df_M[H]=2\operatorname{tr}(M\,X\,H)=2\operatorname{tr}(M\,X\,\circ\,\operatorname{id})[H]$

More generally, $$d(\operatorname{tr}(M^pX))=p\operatorname{tr}(M^{p-1}X\circ\,\operatorname{id})$$